# The endpoints of the Cantor set can be written as $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots a_{n+1}$ base 3

Tags: real-analysis, number-systems, cantor-set

I want to show that the endpoints of the Cantor set can be written as $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots a_{n+1}$ base 3, where each $a_k$ is 0 or 2, except $a_{n+1}$, can be 1 or 2.
I know that any element in the Cantor set can be written in base 3 without using the digit 1, but I don't know about the endpoints. 
How would I go about showing this? I'm not sure where to start

Comment: The endpoints are those decimals that end in all $0$ or in all $2$.

Comment: Why is that? Is there a specific way of writing them that allows one to deduce that?

Comment: Consider a right end point of an interval that has been removed. If it has an infinite expansion to base 3 with coefficients 0 and 2 the you can remove 'far away' term in the series to get a smaller number close to it but still in C ( because its expansion has only the coefficients 0 and 2). But points to the left and close to it are in the interval that is removed! This shows that right end points have finite expansions. I think you can take it from here and complete the proof.